# Redisplay changed custom icon in Icon view(IKImageBrowserView) in Finder 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsworkspace

I am using `setIcon:forFile:options:` method of [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for setting custom icon for file and directory. My problem is that , the Finder is not reflecting icon change in icon view until restart.

Icon view:
[image]

[image]

List view (outline view):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Carbon development tips and tricks](https://developer.apple.com/carbon/tipsandtricks.html#kAESync) .

> You need to send a kAESync AppleEvent to the Finder passing it an
>   alias to the file that was changed.

Below code is written by [JWWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309425/jwwalker)

```
OSStatus    SendFinderSyncEvent( const FSRef* inObjectRef )
{
    AppleEvent  theEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AppleEvent  replyEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AliasHandle itemAlias = NULL;
    const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';

OSStatus    err = FSNewAliasMinimal( inObjectRef, &itemAlias );
if (err == noErr)
{
    err = AEBuildAppleEvent( kAEFinderSuite, kAESync, typeApplSignature,
        &kFinderSig, sizeof(OSType), kAutoGenerateReturnID,
        kAnyTransactionID, &theEvent, NULL, "'----':alis(@@)", itemAlias );

    if (err == noErr)
    {
        err = AESendMessage( &theEvent, &replyEvent, kAENoReply,
            kAEDefaultTimeout );

        AEDisposeDesc( &replyEvent );
        AEDisposeDesc( &theEvent );
    }

    DisposeHandle( (Handle)itemAlias );
}

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Is this similar to calling NSWorkspace's `noteFileSystemChanged:` method?

Comment: Intermittently, it fails. Maybe I should try this sequence instead.

PS, I can't seem to @mention you.

Comment: @radj Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781373/finder-update-refresh-applescript-not-working-in-10-8