# How to refresh Finder Item icon in 10.8?

Tags: macos, icons, osx-mountain-lion, finder

I have issue to refresh finder item icon.

Here is things, I tried.

tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX file \"%@\""

Also tried,

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with i from 1 to count of Finder windows
        tell window i
            try
                update every item with necessity
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

Script is working fine, no error. BUT file icon does not get refresh.

Also read some post which say above script is working fine with 10.7. But after 10.8 icon does not get refreshed. 
Basic problem is to refresh finder cache.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finder update/refresh applescript not working in 10.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781373/finder-update-refresh-applescript-not-working-in-10-8)

Answer (score 0):

Apple needs to be aware there are lots of developers need finder update apple script. File a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com -- it'll likely be closed as a duplicate, but every vote counts.
For now you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15541439/944634) solution.

Comment: Can you please share radar id if any one already filed. Is there any update on that from Apple?

Comment: Can you please link to this bug with id 12571746 i cant find it. Thx

Comment: Can you please link me to it @ParagBafna i type in the id in the search but it returns none.

Comment: You can't see the bugs that other people have reported to Apple.  You should file new bug. Apple uses duplicates as a measure of priority.